# Jekyll Liquid Errors are puzzling me

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have been trying to create a site with Github and I'm new to the whole thing. I have been struggling with a piece of code that has been giving me some headache:

```
{% for item in site.static_files %}
    {% if item.path contains '/archive' %}
        {% if item.path contains 'index.html' == false %}
            {% assign split_path = item.path | split: '/' %}
            <p>{{item.path}}</p>
            {% assign filename = split_path.last %}
            <p>{{ filename }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This generates the following error:

> Error:
>   Liquid Warning: Liquid Syntax Error (line 5): Expected end_of_string but found comparison in "item.path contains 'index.html' == false" in archive/index.html

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
if item.path contains 'index.html' == false
```

With:

```
unless item.path contains 'index.html'
```

Liquid's getting confused.